# Testing an event while an ajax call is in progress using Protractor + Angular

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am using protractor 1.7.0 and angular 1.2.

I have a functionality that when i click a button say 'Load Results' an ajax request is fired, meanwhile  the results are coming back I see a button say 'Cancel Request' (to cancel the ongoing ajax request, this button gets hidden when ajax response is received).

Now to test it in protractor I am wirting something like this

```
//to load the results
element(by.css('#load-results')).click();

//to cancel ongoing ajax request to load results    
element(by.css('.search-cancelled')).then(function(){
  element(by.css('.search-cancelled')).click();
});
```

it gives me an error saying that element is not visible.

As far as i know protractor waits for angular to resolve its promises before executing the next statement. So till the time it reaches this code

```
element(by.css('.search-cancelled')).then(function(){
      element(by.css('.search-cancelled')).click();
    });
```

the ajax call has returned and thats why the element gets hidden.

Is there a way i can make protractor not wait for the angular promise and execute my code when the ajax request is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you could do it this way:

```
$('#load-results').click();
waitElementToBeShown($('.search-cancelled'));
$('.search-cancelled').click();
```

Here is the code for help function:

```
var waitElementToBeShown = function (elm) {
    browser.wait(function () {
        return elm.isPresent();
    },15000);
    browser.wait(function () {
        return elm.isDisplayed();
    },15000);
};
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do here?

I tried to run your code but same thing is happening here also.

Comment: I tried to run your code but same thing is happening here also.
After doing `$('#load-results').click();` protractor waits for the response to come back before executing `waitElementToBeShown`. So essentially it has no effect, as it executes the next statement only when the current statement has executed fully.

Protractor uses selenium internally which uses this style https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#Control_Flows

Comment: if I got initial post correctly you click on some button and after it you receive additional button to cancel AJAX request. I use the same pattern everywhere in my tests and it works fine. Literally this piece of code clicks on the button, ideally once it clicks DOM changes and new element appears, you are waiting for it to the 1. presented in the DOM 2. to be clickable and you click on it

Comment: Are you using angular + protractor?

Comment: yes, we have angular app and protractor + jasmine for e2e tests

Comment: what is the version of protractor you guys are using?